# Compute $\iint_D \ (y^2-x^2)dxdy $ where $D=\{(x,y)| xy\leq 1 , x \leq y \leq x+1\}$

Tags: integration

I need help calculating these double integrals:
 D={(x,y)|$ xy\leq 1 $ ,$ \quad x \leq y \leq x+1 $ }
$$\int\int_D \ {y^2-x^2}dxdy $$

I have two method but It's not equal.

Method 1) Let $ \quad u=y-x ,\quad v= y+x $
$$0 \leq u \leq 1 , \quad - \sqrt{u^2+4}\leq v \leq\sqrt{u^2+4} $$
$$dxdy=|J|dudv \quad (|J|= \frac{1}{2}) $$ 
$$\int\int_D \ {y^2-x^2}dxdy =\int_{0} ^{1}\int_{- \sqrt{u^2+4}} ^{\sqrt{u^2+4}}\ {uv \frac{1}{2}}\quad dudv=0 $$

Method 2)  Let $ \quad u=y-x ,\quad v= xy $
$$0 \leq u \leq 1 , \quad  -\frac{u^2}{4}\leq v \leq1 $$
$$dxdy=|J|dudv \quad (|J|= \frac{1}{x+y}) $$ 
$$\int\int_D \ {y^2-x^2}dxdy =\int_{0} ^{1}\int_{-\frac{u^2}{4}} ^{1}\ {u}\quad dvdu\ne 0 $$

Comment: It seems to me that both jacobian are wrong...I got (x+y) for the second jacobian ..and 2 fort the first one.

Comment: Unrelated: Your encoding of maths is terrible, please study how to do it properly.

Comment: I solve it . y+x>0 , y+x <

Comment: y+x <0  and not separate... answer is 0